# How to click an element if it is found before the wait time expires in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

When I search for a term, sometimes the search result is displayed immediately. I have a wait where it waits for 10 seconds to click the element even if the result is found before it.

How to click the element as soon as the search result is displayed?

Comment: Use explicit wait method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

The sample could be like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("elementId")));
```

This code wil wait until the element will be clickable at least 10 seconds. More information you can get in the documentation [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

According your explanation, you can do like this:

```
List<WebElement> listSearchResults = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By.xpath(""))));
if(listSearchResults.size() > 1){
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(listSearchResults.get(listSearchResults.size()-1))).click();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But I have used List<WebElement> to store the search result. In this case can anyone suggest how to click the result as soon as the result is displayed?

Comment: You cannot click on the list of elements. Would be great to provide the relevant code block

Comment: I am not clicking on the list of elements. I use list to store the count of each search result and I click the last result from the displayed list.
listSearchResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
if(listSearchResults.size()>1)
listSearchResults.get(listSearchResults.size()-1).click();
Also I need to validate all the search results which are displayed.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please have a look and tell me if that, what you want

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Only concern is even if the search result is found immediately it waits for sometime before the element is clicked.

Comment: @hs17 Happy to hear it! It doesn't clicks immediately, because element wasn't clickable. That's why driver wait until element will be clickable and only then clicks. If you are satisfied with my help, please mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your selector")));
```

It will wait for visibility of the element and once it is visible you can click it .
i.e

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your selector")).click();
```

Hope that helps you:)

Comment: When element is visible it doesn't means, that it is clickable.